# Skipping Do While loop because Dir function doesn't recognise files

Tags: excel, vba

I am aiming to split out all the worksheets of my workbook, save them as individual files and then, to each new workbook, add a Guidance worksheet (guidance worksheet is the same for all workbooks). The part of the code works perfectly, filling empty xPath directory with a new workbook for each tab.

The code then completely skips the Do While loop section for no reason. If you comment out the For Each loop, then it works. I have no idea why.

```
Sub SplitWorkbooktoFile()

    Dim xPath As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim file As String

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    xPath = "C:\Users\AH Test\"
    file = Dir(xPath)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    For Each xWs In wb.Sheets
        xWs.Copy
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xPath & "\" & xWs.Name & ".xlsx"
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Next

    Do While Not file = ""
        Workbooks.Open (xPath & file)
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = "User Guidance"
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Guidance").Range("A1:C8").Copy
        wb.Sheets("User Guidance").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        wb.Sheets("User Guidance").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        wb.Sheets("User Guidance").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        wb.Save
        wb.Close
        file = Dir
    Loop

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What is `file` at this point?  As no files have been saved, when you are setting it,  I presume its nothing, so skipping the do.  Need the dir line before the do I think

Comment: I'm a bit surprised it works. If there are no workbooks open other than the one with your code, then your `For` loop will save it and close the active workbook which is the workbook with your code... confused

Comment: @Zac `xWs.Copy` called without parameters [creates a new workbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheets.copy#remarks) with a copy of `xWs`, and makes it active.

Comment: Instead of calling `SaveAs` and reopening the files, put the guidance copying after `xWs.Copy` and only then close the workbook.

Comment: Ahh... didn't know that. Never used it like that before. Thanks for the explanation @GSerg

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Thanks for your help. My corrected final answer is below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @Nathan_Sav for prompting me to the correct answer. Just needed to put the file = dir(xpath) after the for each loop.

```
Sub SplitWorkbooktoFile()

    Dim xPath As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim file As String

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    xPath = "C:\Users\AH Test\"


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    For Each xWs In wb.Sheets
        xWs.Copy
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xPath & "\" & xWs.Name & ".xlsx"
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Next

file = Dir(xPath)

    Do While Not file = ""
        Workbooks.Open (xPath & file)
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = "User Guidance"
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Guidance").Range("A1:C8").Copy
        wb.Sheets("User Guidance").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        wb.Sheets("User Guidance").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        wb.Sheets("User Guidance").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        wb.Save
        wb.Close
        file = Dir
    Loop

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```